# Would there be an issue, for system verilog functional coverage bins with similar sequences?

Tags: system-verilog, system-verilog-assertions

```
covergroup xxxx ;
 yyyy : coverpoint (zzzz)
{
bins sequence_1 = {0=>1=>2=>3};
bins sequence_2 = {0=>1=>2=>3=>4};
bins sequence_3 = {0=>1=>2=>3=>4=>5=>6=>7=>8=>9};
bins sequence_4 = {0=>1=>2=>3=>4=>5=>6=>7=>8=>9=>10=>11=>12=>13=>14=>15=>16=>17};
bins sequence_5 = {0=>1=>2=>3=>4=>5=>6=>7=>8=>9=>10=>11=>12=>13=>14=>15=>16=>17=>18};
bins sequence_6 = {0=>1=>2=>3=>4=>5=>6=>7=>8=>9=>10=>11=>12=>13=>14=>15=>16=>17=>18=>19};

}
 endgroup
```

- zzzz is a counter register which counts from 0 up to 3,4,9,17,18 or 19 depending on its input
- In coding this functional coverage, the idea is to hit either one of the bins if a specific series of transitions occur, only one bin.
- so if the transitions for example goes from 0 to 4 like in sequence_2, would that also hit sequence_1, since the 0 to 3 sequence is present in sequence_1

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if sequence_2 is hit, that implies that sequence_1 is also hit. What you really want is to cover what happens when the counter reaches its limit. i.e. does it go back to 0 or does it stay at the limit in the next cycle? There is no need to elaborate every intermediate value of the counter - a covergroup is not a checker. It is only recording that a certain scenario in your test was achieved.

Comment: its a circular counter which restarts at 0 once the maximum number is reached. So you're recommending that instead of specifying the entire sequence, that i just specify the wrap around transitions? like 
`{3=>0}` instead of `{0=>1=>2=>3}`  - and this implies that the sequence is covered ?

thanks for the swift response :D